# C segmentation fault (core dumped) on fork()

Tags: c, fork

I have an arduino sending tempature down the wire to this server script.
You'll get the jist from the code, but the issue is that when i get my first message coming in the cli outputs `segmentation error (core dumped)` and then both the `readIn()` & `writeOut()` functions are being executed by the same process (both functions run in time with the `sleep(1)` & there is also just 1 process shown under `$ps aux`).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
void writeOut();
void readIn();
int fd[2];

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(){
    printf("init\n");

    /*
    fd[0] = read descriptor
    fd[1] = write descriptor
    */

    int value = 0;
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        /* parent process */
        readIn();
    } else{
        /* child process */
        writeOut();
    }
}
void writeOut(){
    char * value = 'start';
    while(1){
        read(fd[0], &value, MAX_BUF);
        printf("%s\n", value);

    }
}

void readIn(){
    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
    while(1){
        bzero( str, 100);
        read(comm_fd, str, 100);
        printf("S: %s", str);
        write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str)+1);
        write(fd[1], &str, sizeof(str));
        sleep(1);   
    }

    printf("readIn Exit!");
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `pid == 0` means child, not parent as your comments would suggest.

Comment: You should check the return value of `pipe()`. Also, `bzero()` is deprecated. Use `memset()`.

Comment: i don't think what you guys have mentioned is critical. it's strange all branches run in the same process after `fork`. maybe you can try to examine `fork` first, see if it works properly. if you used library not compatible with your machine, especially in embedded system, it's not possible for us to find out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *value = 'start'` in `writeOut()` is wrong. First of, `'start'` is not a string. It's a character literal. Second, if it *were* a string, it would be immutable.

Comment: i changed it to `char value[50];` plus a check on the pipe as suggested in the comments